# How to remove fully qualified names from Android Studio project pane?

Tags: java, android-studio, package

After installing the newest version of Android Studio, package names under the main application package are now displayed fully qualified. So before was:

```
com.spook.myapp
    activities
    data
    models
    viewmodels
    ...
```

And now is:

```
com.spook.myapp
    com.spook.myapp.activities
    com.spook.myapp.data
    com.spook.myapp.models
    com.spook.myapp.viewmodels
    ...
```

This is quite annoying, because there's a lot of noise and project pane became cluttered. Is there an option to display non-fully-qualified package names as it was before?